# Determine $p,r \in\Bbb R$ s. t. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{n})^{r}}{n^{p}}$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $p,r\in\Bbb R$ and consider

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{n})^{r}}{n^{p}}$$

a) **SOLVED** Let $p=1$. Determine all $r \in\Bbb R$ s. t. $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{n})^r}{n^p}$ is convergent.

b) **SOLVED** Determine all $p,r \in\Bbb R$ s. t.$\sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{n})^r}{n^p}$ is convergent.

c) **SOLVED** Consider the function series 
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(\log{n})^x}{n}, \quad x \in \Bbb R$$

Let $r < -1$ and show that the function series is uniformly convergent for all $x \leq r$.

---

Notice: log is the natural one.

Kind regards,

Comment: Better to write $(\log n)^r.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for b: You've already solved the $p=1$ case, good. For other cases you want to start thinking this way: Any positive power of $\ln n$ is whimpy small compared to any positive power of $n$ when $n$ gets large. More precisely, if $a,b > 0$ then $(\ln n)^a/n^b \to 0$ as $n\to \infty,$ no matter how big $a$ is and how small $b$ is. You should learn this at a gut level if you haven't already.

Hint for c: $(\ln n)^x\le (\ln n)^r.$

Comment: For $p>1$. The denominator grows faster than the numerator. Because $\log{n} \leq n, \forall n \in\mathbb{N}$. So $a_n=\frac{(\log n)^{r}}{n^{p}}$ goes to $0$ for $n\to\infty$. By the divergence test the series converges. Is this correct? Is the argument good enought?

Comment: I have solved every problem. Thanks!

Comment: Your first comment is incorrect. $a_n\to 0$ does not imply $\sum a_n$ converges.